# Printing Return values from other class

Tags: java, printing, return

I am very new to java and was playing around with code. I was curious how I might print a return value in class B using System.out.print in class A. I do not want to use System.out.print in class B. I already know how to do it that way.

-------- CLASS A ----------------------------------------

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Moregot {


    public static void main(String[] args){         
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Give giveObj = new Give();
        System.out.println("Enter your First Name ");
        String fNamed = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Last Name ");
        String lNamed = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Age ");
        int theAge = scan.nextInt();
        Give.setInfomation(fNamed, lNamed, theAge);         
        System.out.println("Your Name is  " + giveObj.getfN() + " "+ giveObj.getlN() + " and you are age "+ giveObj.getOld());
    }
}
```

-------- CLASS B ----------------------------------------

```
package Practice2;

public class Give {

    private String _fName, _lName;

    private int _age;

    public static void setInfomation(String fNam, String lNam, int old)
    {   
        String _fName = fNam;
        String _lName = lNam;
        int _age = old; 
    }

    public String getfN(){
        return _fName;
    }

    public String getlN(){
        return _lName;
    }

    public int getOld(){
        return _age;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your Give class should have no static methods or fields, none.

Comment: Question edited: code formatted. Request for a "code solution" deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `setInfomation(...)` should not be a static method, since you are trying to set values of an instance you have created:

```
public void setInfomation(String fNam, String lNam, int old)
{
    _fName = fNam;
    _lName = lNam;
    _age = old;
}
```

Also, don't declare `_fName`, `lName` and `_age` again in the method `setInfomation`, because you are hiding the **fields** declared in the class.

Finally, in the `main` method, call `setInformation` with the instance `giveObj` you have created:

```
giveObj.setInfomation(fNamed, lNamed, theAge);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Give` class change the lines:

```
String _fName = fNam;
String _lName = lNam;
int _age = old;
```

to:

```
_fName = fNam;
_lName = lNam;
_age = old;
```

Also, change:

```
Give.setInfomation(fNamed, lNamed, theAge);
```

to:

```
giveObj.setInfomation(fNamed, lNamed, theAge);
```

and remove the `static` declaration from `setInfomation()`

One problem is that inside the method `setInfomation()` you create NEW variables and assign the values to them instead of assigning the parameters to your class members.

Second problem is that you call `setInfomation()` with `Give` - your class (since it's declared as static) instead of making it non-static and calling it with the instance you created: `giveObj`

Comment: The problem is also that the `setInformation(String, String, String)` method is static :P

Answer (score 0):

- Get rid of all static methods from the Give class. The Moregot class should create Give instances and call their methods, but not call static methods off of the class.
- In fact that `getInformation` method should be replaced by a constructor.
- In the constructor you should use the parameters passed in to set fields of the class, i.e., `this.foo = foo;`
- I would change the main method to where you get all the initial data, and only **then** create a Give object, passing this initial data into its constructor.
- I would give the Give class a decent `toString()` method that returns a String representation of the state of the object. For instance, your method would return a String that holds the values in the name fields and the age field.
- Then any class that holds a Give object can easily print it out by passing the Give object to a `System.out.println(...)` call.
- You will want to read a decent Java textbook to learn the rudiments as all your subsequent programming will build from this. Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel is a good one.

> A coded example reply is preferred

Much better for you to experiment with your own coding as you will learn much more with the effort.